# How to manage standardization of webhook data format?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on a webhook to receive & send data between different APIs. Is there is data way to use data key values in a particular format? 
I am sending data in JSON format.
like

```
var student = {
    firstName : "ABC",
    lastName : "ABC",
    email : "ABC@gmail.com",
    phone : "XXXXXXXXXX",
    address : {
        address1 : "SSSS",
        address2 : "FFFF",
        city : "WWWW",
        state : "ZZZZ",
        postCode : "QQQQQ"
    }
}
```

I just want my data key values must have standardized data e.g. some APIs may be using `firstName` as `f_name, first_name` or simply `name`. So, what is better so that neither my data is rejected nor the data which I'm receiving from the APIs are rejected due to incorrect format.